# converting binary to decimal - results too large

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to implement my own method of converting binary to decimal and I'm following the following example of calculating the decimal value of the binary string `101`:

> 101 => 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 => 1*4 + 0*2 + 1*1 => 4 + 1 => 5

My method is

```
def to_decimal binary
  num_array = binary.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)

  puts num_array.inject { |dec, num| dec + num * 2**(num_array.length-1) }
end
```

This seems to work fine for `1001` which gives `9` but `100` gives `1` and `11010` gives `33` when it should be giving 26. I've tried to look this up but I've found a few different ways to going about this and they're just confusing me even further.

Comment: Are you doing this for education purposes?

Comment: It does so because you are moving in the reverse order.

Comment: @EugZol kind of - I'm not a student, I'm just doing some of the exercises from exercism.io

Comment: @TamerShlash you mean I need to start at the end of the array (index -1)?

Comment: @SoSimple exactly, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
num_array.inject{ |dec, num| dec + num * 2**(num_array.length-1) }
```

You meant this (multiplying by current power, and building decimal from the lowest to the highest power):

```
 num_array.reverse!
 num_array.each_index.inject(0){ |dec, index| dec + num_array[index] * 2**index }
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Thanks so much for explaining!

Comment: You could replace the last line with: `pow = 1; num_array.each_with_object(0) { |n,dec| dec += n*pow; pow *= 2 }`